# Pylint error message on holoviews.opts: Class 'opts' has no 'Curve' member

Tags: python, pylint, holoviews

While this code snippets sets the options for `hv.Curve`-plot correctly

```py
import holoviews as hv

hv.opts.defaults(
    hv.opts.Curve(
        color='blue',
        width=500,  
        ylim=(0,4200)
    )
)
```

I get the following error message from pylint: `Class 'opts' has no 'Curve' member`.

When I type `hv.opts.` I get the following options shown in the IDE:
[image]

When I start typing `hv.opts.C[urve]`, I get shown `Curve` as available option:
[image]

Is there any way to make this error disappear without simply silencing it?

Comment: What IDE is this?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: I think it's a pylint limitation as [`opts`](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/blob/v1.13.0a16/holoviews/util/__init__.py#L50) is a bit "special" because it's a `ParameterizedFunction`, and it really does not have a `Curve` attribute. Maybe that's why the Holoviews source uses Flake8 as its linter.

Comment: @Gino Mempin: Thanks for your suggestion of flake8. I gave that a try, and I don't get that error message there.

Comment: This is all correct, `opts` is populated dynamically depending on the plotting backend you load.